# python's negative threshold, the lowest non-infinity negative number?

Tags: python, numbers, threshold, infinity

What is python's threshold of representable negative numbers? What's the lowest number below which Python will call any other value a - negative inifinity?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241832/most-negative-value-for-python

Comment: Python longs are limited only by the memory in your machine.  There is no single practical answer.

Comment: @recursive The question doesn't specify integers, only numbers. There is a smallest non-infinite float, and "infinity" as an actual value does imply (at least a little) floating-point values.

Comment: Longs are numbers too, and they go lower than the lowest finite float.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no most negative integer, as Python integers have arbitrary precision. The smallest float greater than negative infinity (which, depending on your implementation, can be represented as `-float('inf')`) can be found in `sys.float_info`.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.float_info.max
1.7976931348623157e+308
```

The actual values depend on the actual implementation, but typically uses your C library's `double` type. Since floating-point values typically use a sign bit, the smallest negative value is simply the inverse of the largest positive value. Also, because of how floating point values are stored (separate mantissa and exponent), you can't simply subtract a small value from the "minimum" value and get back negative infinity. Subtracting 1, for example, simply returns the same value due to limited precision.

(In other words, the possible `float` values are a small subset of the actual real numbers, and operations on two `float` values is not necessarily equivalent to the same operation on the "equivalent" reals.)

Comment: This is the correct idea, except you are showing the largest float less than positive infinity.  You need the negative sign, so the expression should be >>> -sys.float_info.max

Comment: Another way to get the largest negative number for a floating-point type using numpy is `np.nextafter(-np.inf, 0)`, or `np.nextafter(-np.inf, 0, dtype=np.float32)`. This also works for the smallest non-zero positive number `np.nextafter(0, np.inf)`

Comment: @ybull your solution would lead to overflow so it doesn't work

Comment: `-sys.float_info.max` is fine, though I'm not positive it's actually the most negative finite `float` you can represent.

Comment: @newman_ash -sys.float_info.max does not overflow for me on recent versions of Python. Maybe yours is old? Or possibly it's an OS or hardware-dependent thing? (I've tested on 64-bit Intel Mac and M1 Mac with Python 3.7 & 3.9)